# How to parse DateTime in this format? "Sun May 23 22:00:00 UTC+0300 2010"

Tags: c#, datetime

This is a quick one, i wanna parse a date that comes in this format "Sun May 23 22:00:00 UTC+0300 2010" 
Is this a valid UTC DateTime? And how to parse it? I tried :

```
DateTime newStartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(hdnNewStartTime.Value, "ddd MM dd HH:mm:ss UTC+0300 yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

However, this didn't work, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s,"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTCzzzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Awesome! Working like a charm. the zzzz in the right way to indicate time zones. In my attempt I translated the time zone literally "UTC+0300" which would surely break if the app is deployed to another place with different time zone. Thanks johncatfish!

Answer (score 2):

Its  not a standard format, but you can still parse it.

```
        string format = "ddd mmm dd HH:mm:ss zzzzz yyyy";
        string temp = "Sun May 23 22:00:00 UTC+0300 2010";
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't in a standard .NET format, so you'll probably have to parse it by hand.  The `UTC+0300` bit indicates the timezone, everything else is part of the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution presented by @johncatfish and it does what I expect. I would presume that you actually want to keep the timezone information.

```
[Test()]
public void TestCaseWorks ()
{
    string format = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss UTCzzzzz yyyy";
    string temp = "Sun May 23 22:00:00 UTC+0300 2010";
    DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(temp, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    Assert.AreEqual(DayOfWeek.Sunday, time.DayOfWeek);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, time.Month);
    Assert.AreEqual(23, time.Day);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, time.Minute);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, time.Second);
    Assert.AreEqual(2010, time.Year);

    // Below is the only actually useful assert -- making sure the
    // timezone was parsed correctly.

    // In my case, I am GMT-0700, the target time is GMT+0300 so
    // 22 + (-7 - +3) = 12 is the expected answer. It is an exercise
    // for the reader to make a robust test that will work in any
    // timezone ;).

    Assert.AreEqual(12, time.Hour);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous answer which was quite simplistic.
Replace MM by MMM in your date format and it should be fine.

Comment: Oh yeah, sure :) I mean, of course, but the problem is with the custom format. DateTime.Parse("SSun May 23 22:00:00 UTC+0300 2010"); will through a FormatException. So!

Answer (score 0):

From the example given, it isn't possible to tell if the month should be in the 3 letter form (Jan, Feb, May etc.) or in the full form (January, February, May etc.).

If it should be in the short form, use:

[ddd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dddSpecifier) [MMM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier) [dd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) [HH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier):[mm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier):[ss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ssSpecifier) UTC[zzz](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) [yyyy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yyyySpecifier)

If it should be in the long form, use:

[ddd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dddSpecifier) [MMMM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMMM_Specifier) [dd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddSpecifier) [HH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#HH_Specifier):[mm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#mmSpecifier):[ss](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ssSpecifier) UTC[zzz](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzzSpecifier) [yyyy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#yyyySpecifier)

Details of the formatting specifiers available can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx